# Updating a single row in Recyclerview with binding and Livedata

Tags: android, data-binding, android-recyclerview, realm, android-livedata

I have a `Recyclerview` setup with `databinding` and `LiveData`, using a Realm Database.

It's working for the most part, except that the `Recyclerview` doesn't update the rows properly.

In my Dao I am fetching my `LiveData` results as such. (it has no problem populating the `Recyclerview`):

```
fun getList(): LiveData<RealmResults<Entity>>{
    return db.where(Entity::class.java).sort("sortKey",Sort.DESCENDING).findAllAsync().asLiveData()
}
```

My `ViewModel` sets up the data as such:

```
val realm: Realm by lazy {
    Realm.getDefaultInstance()
}

private var entityDao = EntityDao(realm)

init {
    myEntities = Transformations.map(EntityDao.getList()){ input -> input }
}
```

Here is the `Recyclerview` setup that I have in my `Fragment`:

```
binding.savedPostsRecyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager((activity as Context?)!!)

binding.vm?.myEntities?.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer{
    it?.let {
        adapter.submitList(it)
    }
})
```

In my fragment as well, here is where I update my database and saves it to `Realm` (which does update):

```
adapter = EntityAdapter(EntityListener { entity ->
        realm.executeTransaction {
            entity.uploadState = "uploading"
            it.copyToRealmOrUpdate(entity)
        }

}
```

Here where I bind my `Adapter` items:

```
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
    holder.bind(getItem(position)clickListener)
}

fun bind(item: Entity, clickListener: SavedMapEntityListener) {
      binding.dbEntity = item
      binding.clickListener = clickListener
      binding.executePendingBindings(
}
```

I am using a `DiffUtil` to listen to the changes:

```
class EntityDiffCallback : DiffUtil.ItemCallback<Entity>() {


    override fun areItemsTheSame(oldItem: Entity, newItem: Entity): Boolean {
        return oldItem.id == newItem.id
    }

    override fun areContentsTheSame(oldItem: Entity, newItem: Entity): Boolean {
        return oldItem.equals(newItem)
    }
}
```

I have 2 problems here.

1- When I add an item to my `LiveData<RealmResults<Entity>>`, I can see that the `Realm` database is updated, and I can see that an additional item is added at the bottom of my `Recyclerview` even though it should appear at the top and the added item appears as a copy of the previous item.

2- I have a `Button` in each cell that should change color when tapped. Even though I am getting confirmation that the button is being pressed, the row doesn't update itself.

Here are my questions: How do I update the `Recyclerview` properly to reflect changes when an item is added or a row `Button` is tapped?

Comment: 1. why not sort the item before publish in recyelceview.
2. check if the list in adapter is same ref of list in live data. if its same. the notifdatachanged not working. u need fresh copy of list to fix that (cause i do that)

Comment: I do sort my list '.sort("sortKey",Sort.DESCENDING)' when first generating it. So you are saying that to see the changes I need to generate a new list?

Comment: yeah i always sort new list and fresh copy (you can use in IO thread or Computation) before submitList() cause when not do fresh copy the list inside adapter and list from live data is same reference, its mean DiffUtil.ItemCallback with not call notif data changed cause they think list same as before cause reference. (https://codeshare.io/G6rJlk)